# MappingProxyType equivalent for lists and other sequences

Tags: python, data-structures

I recently discovered [MappingProxyType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType), which provides a

> Read-only proxy of a mapping. It provides a dynamic view on the mapping’s entries, which means that when the mapping changes, the view reflects these changes.

This seems really useful if, for example, you have a class instance with an internal dict, which you want to be able to provide to users of the instance for inspection, but not to allow them to modify it. Providing a mappingproxy provides a more efficient alternative to providing a copy of the dict. Users can inspect the dict via the mappingproxy, but an exception is raised if they try to mutate it.

It occurs to me that it would be useful if there were something similar for lists. I know that generators can be used for this purpose, but you can't index into a generator to get the nth element.

Does a MappingProxyType equivalent for lists, tuples etc. exist in Python?

Comment: You don't need that for a tuple because they are already read-only, though.

Comment: But suppose you have a very long list as the value of an instance attribute. Say you need this to be a list because it has to be mutable, but you also want to provide access to the list to users of the class. You could copy this into a list and return the list to the user of the instance. But if there are thousands of items in that list, it seems pretty inefficient to copy the whole list when all you really want to do is allow for reading of its items.

Comment: I didn't say you don't need that for a list

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. I take your point that there would be no need to use a proxy like this to provide a 'view' of a tuple.

Comment: I don't understand why `MappingProxyType` doesn't support lists.  A list is just a mapping from a limited range of integers to objects.